# Custom Authorizer + Stages configuration values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, auth0

We have a custom authorizer for Auth0 configured in API Gateway. We want it to load different configuration values based on what stage it is invoked from. Is there a known way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. If you want to use the same authorizer function for both stages, you can parse the [input passed to the function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-input) which includes the stage:

   ```
   {
     "type":"TOKEN",
     "authorizationToken":"<caller-supplied-token>",
     "methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<apiId>/<stage>/<method>/<resourcePath>"
   }
   ```
2. If you want to use different functions per stage you can make use of stage variables. **Note:** You will have to use the CLI or SDK to add an authorizer with a stage variable. An example with the CLI:

   ```
   aws apigateway update-authorizer --rest-api-id <apidId> --authorizer-id <authorizerId> --patch-operations '[{"op":"replace","path":"/authorizerUri","value":"arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<accountId>:function:${stageVaribles.authorizer}/invocations"}]'
   ```

Comment: Thanks! We chose to go with Option 1. I think for larger deployments where more configuration churn could exist #2 would require deployment scripting.

Comment: var methodArn = event.methodArn.split('/')[1] || "development";
config = environments[methodArn];